# Box-Sizing doesn't seem to honor padding the way I expect

Tags: css, layout

Can someone tell me why the box-sizing doesn't seem to honor the padding in the div given the following [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MFFdM/)

```
// The code is too long for this but can be viewed using browser debugging tools
// and here is a picture that says it all.
```

[image]

The left column is fixed width: 190px;

The right column is width:100% with a margin-left: 190px

The green div is a nested div without a width and height:20px;

```
 <style>
  div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
 </style>
```

Shouldn't the padding push the green line in as it is on the left side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this instance is with the `#wizard-body` div, which has a left margin but also a width of `100%`, which means it's way to wide for *its* container. The float also messes things up. Remove these and it will work as expected:

```
#wizard-body {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The green div is behaving as expected, but is following the container off screen.

Comment: You are most certainly correct. That helps quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

`box-sizing:border-box` does not remove the padding. It just dont take it into account when calculating width of div.

`div {width:400px; padding:10px;}` will give a div with width of 420px as width also includes padding.

But

`div {width:400px; padding:10px; box-sizing:border-box;}` will give a div with width of 400px since it does not includes padding.

But in both cases padding remains there.

Comment: what you want to do exactly?

Comment: The right side should indent the same as the left on the second column. I just added the green div to demonstrate the problem

Comment: Check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MFFdM/5/ Is this what you want? I've change some more css also ('wizard-body' is much larger that expected, so have to edit few more styles).